# How to remotely connect to a laptop's local users directory?

Tags: open-directory

besides opening ssh-  is there a way to connect and read local users defined in a machine?

**Edit** - further info.

My goal is to actually run an analysis on my network - to find out which local accounts reside in which machine.
the thing is that not all machines have ssh opened.

All the machines are part of my domain, and i have an administrative user and password in order to connect to the machines.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to *administer* machines in your charge or are you just looking for a way to hack your way into someone's machine without their knowledge?

Comment: I'm not trying to hack anyone. i'm trying to make a list of local accounts that might reside on our laptops, let's assume i have an administrator's password already, so where's the hacking here?

Comment: Allan's question is a legitimate one. You should edit your question to include pertinent information about the ownership of, and administrative access to, these Macs. We're just trying to be cautious in an effort to prevent malicious and/or illegal activity. Some of us on AskDifferent have responsibilities for maintaining security on our machines and networks, and blanket question like yours ring warning bells. That's all.

Comment: Allright, i've edited my question.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you *can't* open `ssh` on all machines? If you have admin access to all machines anyway this will make things much easier.

Comment: Well, i'm not sure what's the best practice. usually ssh is opened for specific users? i understand that are other options like "Remote Management" which is an apple software.

Comment: ssh is there specifically for you to remotely login/administer the machine.  If you are concerned about security, you could configure `sshd` to use a different port than the default (port 22).  Additionally, you could configure `sshd` to only allow access via SSH key and passphrase which means users/hackers won't be able to access via traditional interactive (username/password) methods.

Answer (score -1):

You can get a list of all macOS-accounts with

```
 dscl . list /Users | grep -v '_'
```

*daemon*, *nobody*, and *root* are system-defined accounts. So here you have the list of all local users.

Comment: The problem is that i need to do it remotely.